# ffmpeg with Axis P1347 returns 400 Bad Request, but Axis 1357 works

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I have two cameras: an Axis P1347 and an Axis P1357.  `ffmpeg` gets a `400 Bad Request` on the P1347 but everything works fine with the P1357.

I am able to **successfully** stream rtsp video using **vlc** from an **Axis P1347 Camera** using the following url:

```
rtsp://10.8.3.85:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&audio=1
```

However, this same url in **ffmpeg** gives the following for the **Axis P1347 Camera**:

```
root@ubuntu4-virtual-machine:/home/ubuntu4# ffmpeg -re -v verbose  -i "rtsp://10.8.3.85:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&audio=1"
ffmpeg version git-2016-05-02-9fcb59c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      55. 23.100 / 55. 23.100
  libavcodec     57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavformat    57. 35.100 / 57. 35.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 44.100 /  6. 44.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
rtsp://10.8.3.85:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&audio=1: Server returned 400 Bad Request
```

The same **ffmpeg** command works great with the nearly identical **Axis P1357 Camera** :

```
root@ubuntu4-virtual-machine:/home/ubuntu4# ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://10.8.3.90:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&audio=1"
ffmpeg version git-2016-05-02-9fcb59c Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      55. 23.100 / 55. 23.100
  libavcodec     57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavformat    57. 35.100 / 57. 35.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 44.100 /  6. 44.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.8.3.90:554/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&audio=1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.083300, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2592x1944 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 12 tbr, 90k tbn
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp
```

Obviously `rtsp` is turned on and working if vlc can display video, correct?  So why does VLC work with the camera, but not ffmpeg?  Note ffmpeg is installed and works correctly with a similar camera.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the P1347 is outputting a 64 bit codec which ffmpeg does not have codecs to ingest.  VLC had the 64 bit codecs installed.

I will research how to install 64 bit codecs and use them for the P1347 camera.